# Use debug API key over ADB with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services, api-key

I'm trying to use Google Maps in my App. I created an debug certificate which is saved in debug.keystore. I registered it at code.google.com (with correct project package) and copied the api key to the android manifest. I have all needed Permissions, i use

```
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

and i have

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I still get an error when i install the app on my device with ADB (using the eclipse android plugin and the start button). How can i fix that (i checked the certificate and the api key already multiple times)?

Comment: Wait. I only see the google sign and the plus and minus button, posting log right now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. I instantly found the error when trying to copy the log. (after 1 h searching)

The problem was that i changed my package name. In logcat i saw that in the Android manifest, a different package name was contained.